# Compile a Java Application to leverage Kafka

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I am using the following to write a message producer:

- Maven
- Java 1.8
- Ubuntu

My pom.xml file has this entry from http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theproducer

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I issued here is what my HelloWorld.java app looks like:

```
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;

public class HelloWorld
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                int x = 4;
                System.out.println("hello world");
        }
}
```

I then compile using Maven.

```
mvn compile
```

But I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] /home/azureuser/test-application/src/main/java/HelloWorld.java:
            [6,30] package kafka.javaapi.producer does not exist
```

Does anyone know what is missing?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In your IDE, does it say this package exists in the project?

Comment: incorrect import : it should be 
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;

Answer (score 1):

Based on my [search on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C2%7Cfc%3A%22kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer%22) it looks like your defined dependency is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look into your .m2 repository and find the jar (.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar) file, and you will see that the import should be:

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct import should be `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer`.
Check the `packages` section at the bottom [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.0)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. It is the solution.